# How to build custom pipeline in GCP using Vertex AI

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-training

I was exploring the vertex AI AutoML feature in GCP, which lets users import datasets, train, deploy and predict ML models. My use case is to do the data pre-processing on my own (I didn't get satisfied with AutoML data preprocessing) and want to feed that data directly to a pipeline where it trains and deploys the model.
Also, I want to feed the new data to the dataset. It should take care of the entire pipeline (from data preprocessing to deploying the latest model).
I want insight as to how to approach this problem?

Comment: Hi koushik. did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom pipeline using Kubeflow Pipelines SDK v1.8.9 or higher or TensorFlow Extended v0.30.0 or higher.

- If you use TensorFlow in an ML workflow that processes terabytes of structured data or text data, it is recommended  that you build your pipeline using TFX.
- For other use cases, we recommend that you build your pipeline using the Kubeflow Pipelines SDK. By building a pipeline with the Kubeflow Pipelines SDK, you can implement your workflow by building custom components or reusing pre-built components.

To create a Kubeflow pipeline, you can follow the next [guide](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/build-pipeline#before_you_begin)